# jQuery behaviors

Tags: theming, javascript

I'm designing my first drupal theme and I'm not very well experienced in this kind of stuffs.
I tried to add some jQuery to my design so I saved this code into a `.js` file and add it to my `theme.info` file:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("button").hide();
    };
};
```

It should work properly but it didn't. After some searching, find out for avoiding conflicts I should use drupal's function instead of `$(document).ready` so I did:

```
(function ($) {
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("button").hide();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

but it doesn't work out. And again, by googling I find out something named behaviors. Actually I can't understand what is it but after using examples as a pattern an overwriting my code into it, my issue fixed:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("#navigation").hide();
    });
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

So my question is: **What is drupal behaviors?**

I read some articles about it but couldn't understand it well.

Also some examples will appreciated.

Comment: See also https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors